# How to extract parameter in Pycharm without forcing a default value?

Tags: python, pycharm

It seems that the only option when extracting a parameter in a function when using PyCharm is to add the selected object as a default value of the new parameter. Sometimes it's better to replace all the usages of said function with the selected object, like in IntelliJ, the Java IDE from the same creators as Pycharm.

I'm aware that default values are not allowed in Java but having a feature in Python doesn't mean it's always the best choice. It would be nice to have the option of choosing one of the following when extracting (or introducing) a parameter when using Pycharm:

1. Change the signature of the function by adding a new parameter and add the selected object as its default value (actual behavior)
2. Change the signature of the function by adding a new parameter and change all of its usages to call the function with the selected parameter (behavior not available)

Is there a way to extract a parameter as in option 2?

For example, in a test class I may instantiate the target class' objects in a function like below

```
from unittest import TestCase

EMAIL ="a@b.com"

# Placeholder for object creation (a class' constructor, for example)
create_object = lambda email: "an object"


class Test(TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        test_object = self.get_test_object()
        # ...

    def test_2(self):
        test_object = self.get_test_object()
        # ...

    def test_3(self):
        test_object = self.get_test_object()
        # ...

    def get_test_object(self):
        # Use the EMAIL constant to create a test_object
        test_object = create_object(EMAIL)
        return test_object
```

Now imagine that I want to add the email as a parameter to the function "get_test_object" instead of using the global variable "EMAIL". In Pycharm I right click in EMAIL -> Refactor -> Introduce Parameter and type in the parameter name. This won't change the usages and will only set a new parameter with a default value as shown below

```
def get_test_object(self, email=EMAIL):
    # Use the EMAIL constant to create a test_object
    test_object = create_object(email)
return test_object
```

If I wanted to use the function with another email, I could do it by calling "get_test_object('c@d.com')" but the other usages of the function would force the reader to check what email it is implicitly using. In this case I think it would be better if it changed all the usages instead of adding a default value so when adding a new use of the function it would like this:

```
from unittest import TestCase

EMAIL ="a@b.com"

# Placeholder for object creation (a class' constructor, for example)
create_object = lambda email: "an object"    

class Test(TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        test_object = self.get_test_object(EMAIL)
        # ...

    def test_2(self):
        test_object = self.get_test_object(EMAIL)
        # ...

    def test_3(self):
        test_object = self.get_test_object(EMAIL)
        # ...

    def test_4(self):
        test_object = self.get_test_object("c@d.com")
        # ...

    def get_test_object(self, email):
        test_object = create_object(email)
        return test_object
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to do this was in 2 steps:

1. As shown above, right click in EMAIL -> Refactor -> Introduce Parameter and type in the parameter name
2. Right click in the "email" parameter of the function (not the value) -> Refactor -> Change Signature -> Untick "Use default value in signature"

[image]

Doing 1 and then 2 will extract a parameter and change all the function usages to include it in the call as originally desired. Nevertheless, it's too cumbersome. It would be better to do this in only 1 step.